# How to apply custom theme to the visuals?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an embedded report in which I want to set the theme of the visuals according to the even and odd number of visuals. I am able to check the number of visuals by getting count of all the filters. Can anyone suggest how can I apply the theme to the visuals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply themes to the visuals, please find the below code snippet:

1. Create customized themes:

```js
var themes = [
{
"name": "light",
"dataColors": ["#93A299","#057BE0","#848058"],
"background": "#FFFFFF",
"foreground": "#CF543F",
"tableAccent": "#93A299"
},
{
"name": "dark",
"dataColors": ["#31B6FD","#4584D3", "#5BD078"],
"background": "#000000",
"foreground": "#4584D3",
"tableAccent": "#31B6FD"
}
]
```

2. Get the number of visuals:

```js
const visuals = await page.getVisuals();
const num_of_visuals = visuals.length;
```

3. Use `applyTheme` API to apply themes to visuals:

```js
// Apply the custom theme for even number of visuals
if(num_of_visuals % 2 == 0){
report.applyTheme({ themeJson: themes.find(theme => theme.name ==="light")});
}
else { // Apply the custom theme for odd number of visuals
report.applyTheme({ themeJson: themes.find(theme => theme.name === "dark") });
}
```

You Can find the reference from the below links:

[Get pages and visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visuals)

[Apply Report Themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/apply-report-themes)